# Single entry with 450 Matrix blocks throwing error on save

Tags: matrix, singles

A client has a Singles entry with a Matrix block defined that contains a few text fields, and one image field. They've created approximately 450 instances of this Matrix block, and can no longer update the page. Craft throws a 500 error. Craft logs just show a basic

`exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /srv/[clientName]/releases/20170418025256/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59`

and nothing of use in the Apache error logs. Anyone have experience with this sort of error, or confidence that this would be a Craft bug?

Comment: Is the HTTP 500 error Craft-styled or is it a general webserver HTTP 500 error?

Comment: Craft-styled, sorry should have specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you're bumping into `php.ini` limitations.  I'd bump the values of [memory_limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), [post_max_size](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and [max_input_vars](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) and see if that helps.

They are common culprits when POSTing large amounts of data (which is what 450 Matrix Blocks would be considered).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. The memory allocation was pretty hefty, but I hadn't thought to look at `post_max_size` or `max_input_vars`. Upped both and it's usable again.

Comment: One note -- `post_max_size` allows `0M` as a setting for unlimited size, but Craft will apply this literally to asset uploads as a size limit of 0, so should be specified as a large number if you want to increase it.